# Simple DRY Rails - check if a model belongs to a user

Tags: beginner, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I can clearly see I'm repeating myself, but I don't know how to refractor this without making it really ugly. What I have:

```
class ChildModelController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @model = ParentModel.find(params[:id])
        # Does the current user have permissions on the parent model    
        if signed_in?
          unless current_user.admin? or current_user.id == @model.user_id
            flash[:error] = t('errors.messages.not_authorized')
            flash.keep
            redirect_to root_path
          end
        else
          unless session and session[:session_id] == @model.author_session_token
            flash[:error] = t('errors.messages.not_authorized')
            flash.keep
            redirect_to root_path
          end
        end
        #do stuff to the model
    end

end
```

The only way I can think to make it smaller is to make it ugly:

```
class ChildModelController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @model = ParentModel.find(params[:id])
        # Does the current user have permissions on the parent model    
        if (!signed_in? and session and session[:session_id] == @model.author_session_token ) || (signed_in and current_user.admin? or current_user.id == @model.user_id)
            flash[:error] = t('errors.messages.not_authorized')
            flash.keep
            redirect_to root_path
          end

        #do stuff to the model
    end

end
```

Am I missing an even easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you extract two methods: `authorized?` to check if the user is authorized, and `not_authorized` to handle behaviour. You would then end up with this:

```
def new
  @model = ParentModel.find(params[:id])
  not_authorized unless authorized?
end

private

def authorized?
  if signed_in?
    # If you have your associations setup correctly you don't have 
    # to check equality on id. You can just compare the objects
    current_user.admin? || current_user == @model.user
  else
    # See aside number 2 for why I removed session
    # session[:session_id] will return nil if it's not present
    # which is false in ruby, so it's safe to do this
    session[:session_id] == @model.author_session_token
  end
end

def not_authorized
  flash[:error] = t('errors.messages.not_authorized')
  flash.keep
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

But I suggest you think about using an authorisation library, or extracting authorisation logic into a policy object. This way you gain the benefit of DRY, and an extensible way to add and reuse permissions.

```
def new
  @model = ParentModel.find(params[:id])
  not_authorized unless authorized?(current_user, @model)
end
```

In a separate policy object you could:

```
# Choose a better name for this
class ModelPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :model

  def initialize(user, model)
    @user, @model = user, model
  end

  def authorized?
    user.admin? || user.id == model.user_id
  end
end
```

This example illustrates my point but it is not complete. You must wire the policy to the controllers, maybe include it in a concern. But it's not that hard.

[There's a great gem called Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) that gives you similar interface.

### Asides

1. Try not to use `unless` with `||` and `&&` conditions because it becomes confusing. It's clearer to use negation: `!current_user`. Some people are boolean impaired, including myself.
2. I'm not sure under what circumstances the `session` hash does not exist. So checking for its presence may be redundant.

Comment: I am actually using Pundit for other things, but I haven't had the time to dive deep into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm not understanding something about your code, can't you just
move the duplicated code into a method?

```
class ChildModelController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @model = ParentModel.find(params[:id])
    # Does the current user have permissions on the parent model
    if signed_in?
      unless current_user.admin? or current_user.id == @model.user_id
        not_authorized
      end
    else
      unless session and session[:session_id] == @model.author_session_token
        not_authorized
      end
    end
    #do stuff to the model
  end

  def not_authorized
    flash[:error] = t('errors.messages.not_authorized')
    flash.keep
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

The conditions are fine as they are, maybe you should move them into a separate `check_auth` method when `new` gets longer, or you need the same checks in other places.

Comment: Oh your understanding it. I just was trying to fix my conditionals so much I didn't think of that (doh).